# issue generating triangular wave function in Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to create a model where one Modelica variable is a triangular wave of another variable. First I tried the floor() function as below:

```
model test1
  final constant Real pi=2*Modelica.Math.asin(1.0);
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real a = 1;
  Real x,p,u;
equation
  if sign(sin(x*pi/b))>=0 then 
    p=a*(x-b*floor(x/b));
  else 
    p=a*(b-(x-b*floor(x/b)));
  end if;
  x=time;
  u = floor(x/b);
end test1
```

(x=time; is arbitrary so the model compiles)

but the result is weird, as you can see below
[image]

zoom in:

[image]

somehow 0.005 seconds before the next step floor function behaves unexpectedly and becomes a linear function ending by the next value.

[image]

then I tried the ceil() function. everything seemed right till I realised the same problem happens with ceil() function at other values (e.g. x=13)

I would appreciate if you could:

1. help me understand why this "glitch" happens and if it is intentional by design or a bug?
2. how I can fix this?
3. are there any alternatives to create a triangular wave function?

P.S. I am using this "wave function" to model the interaction between two jagged bodies"

Answer (score 4):

If you are allowed to utilize the Modelica Standard Library, you can build up a parametrized, time-based zigzag signal using the CombiTimeTable block with linear interpolation and periodic extrapolation. For example,

```
model Test4
  parameter Real a=2 "Amplitude";
  parameter Real b=3 "Period";
  Real y=zigzag.y[1] "Zigzag";
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.CombiTimeTable zigzag(
    table=[0,0;b/4,a;b/4,a;b/2,0;b/2,0;3*b/4,-a;3*b/4,-a;b,0],
    extrapolation=Modelica.Blocks.Types.Extrapolation.Periodic)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,60},{-60,80}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Trapezoid trapezoid(
    amplitude=2*a,
    rising=b/2,
    width=0,
    falling=b/2,
    period=b,
    offset=-a)
    annotation(Placement(transformation(extent={{-80,25},{-60,45}})));
  annotation(uses(Modelica(version="3.2.2")));
end Test4;
```

Comment: thanks a lot. please consider that I'm very new to the whole Modelica world so my apology in advance if my questions seems stupid: First of all I tried your code, it does compile successfully but the only two parameters possible to draw are constants a and b. Would you please add other variables to your code, like x and y, which could be drawn? coming from a C background I'm not familiar with the whole block concept otherwise I would add it myself. second point is that there is also a Trapezoid block in Modelica standard library. why not using that?

Comment: I updated the `Test4` model to have the desired output variable `y`. The `x=time` is implicit for CombiTimeTable, thus there is no possiblilty to other input than time.

Yes, you can also use the trapezoid signal, but only shifted in time, see also `Test4`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an explanation for the glitches in your simulation.

However, I would take another approach to the sawtooth function: I see it as an integrator integrating +1 and -1 upwards and downwards. The integration time determines the amplitude and period of the sawtooth function.

The pictures below show an implementation using MSL blocks and one using code. The simulation results below are the same for both implementations.

Best regards, 
Rene Just Nielsen

**Block diagram:**
[image: Block diagram implementation]
**Code:**

```
model test3
  parameter Real a=2 "amplitude";
  parameter Real b=3 "period";

  Real u, y;
initial equation 
  u = 1;
  y = 0;
equation 
  4*a/b*u = der(y);
  when y > a then
    u = -1;
  elsewhen y < -a then
    u = 1;
  end when;
end test3;
```

**Simulation result:**
[image]

Comment: I have another issue: as you may see in the question, I want to have a function p=func(x), where x is an arbitrary function of time. your code depends on a constant signal u. can you modify it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem I guess is due to floating point representation and events not occurring at exact times.

Consider `x-floor(x)` and `1-(x-floor(x))` at time=0.99, they are `0.99` and `0.01`; at time=1.00 they are `0.0` and `1.0`, which causes your problems.

For a=b=1, you can use the following equation for p:
`p=min(mod(x,2),2-mod(x,2));`. You can even add `noEvent` to it, and you can consider the signal continuous (but not differentiable).

```
model test
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real a = 3;
  Real x, p;
equation
  p = 2*a*min(1 / b * mod(x, b ),1 - 1/b * mod(x, b));
  x = time;
end test;
```

Comment: I think the mod() function worths a try. would you mind adding the code to your answer? I would also appreciate if you could : 1. let me know more about noEvent() function in simple words. I tried to read about it but didn't completely comprehend. 2. let me know why some signals which are theoretically non-differentiable, are ok in Modelica, but others aren't? for example the floor() function shouldn't be differentiable but OpenModelica compiles without any error

Comment: `noEvent` makes it so the solver does not try to find the zero-crossing at run-time. Basically, you don't really know if you get a time just after the event or not. Sometimes, there can be unexpected things occurring for conditions in if-expressions if there is no noEvent present. And regarding differentiable functions: they are only necessary when performing index-reduction (or if the tool relies on Jacobians). Some functions are piece-wise differentiable and might also work (if the function gives an event, since the derivative is not used during the event and present to the left and right).

Answer (score 2):

My first advise would be to remove the sign-function, since there is no benefit of doing `sign(foo)>=0` compared to `foo>=0`.

Interesting enough that seems to fix the problem in Dymola - and I assume also in OpenModelica:

```
model test1 "almost original"
  final constant Real pi=2*Modelica.Math.asin(1.0);
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real a = 1;
  Real x,p,u;
equation
  if sin(x*pi/b)>=0 then 
    p=a*(x-b*floor(x/b));
  else 
    p=a*(b-(x-b*floor(x/b)));
  end if;
  x=time;
  u = floor(x/b);
end test1;
```

Now I only have to explain that - and the reason is that `sin(x*pi/b)` is slightly out of sync with the floor-function, but if you use `sin(x*pi/b)>=0` that is within the root-finding epsilon and nothing strange happen.

When you use `sign(sin(x*pi/b))>=0` that is no longer possible, instead of having `sin(x*pi/b)` an epsilon below zero it is now -1, and instead of epsilon above zero it is 1.

The real solution is thus slightly more complicated:

```
model test2 "working"
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real a = 1;
  Real x,p,u;
  Real phase=mod(x,b*2);
equation 
  if phase<b then
    p=a/b*phase;
  else
    p=a-a/b*(phase-b);
  end if;
  x=time;
  u = floor(x/b);
end test2;
```

which was improved based on a suggested solution:

```
model test3 "almost working"
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real a = 1;
  Real x,p,u;
equation
  if mod(x,2*b)<b then 
    p=a/b*mod(x,b);
  else 
    p=a-a/b*mod(x,b);
  end if;
  x=time;
  u = floor(x/b);
end test3;
```

The key point in this solution, test2, is that there is only one problematic event generating expression `mod(x,2*b)` - and the `<` will not get out of sync with this.

In practice test3 will almost certainly also work, but in unlikely cases the event generation might get out of sync between `mod(x,2*b)` and `mod(x,b)`; with unknown consequences.

Note that all three examples are now modified to generate output that looks similar.

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your answer. your second code is the first solution in this page which generates a contains signal. second, in your second code it seems that b is half period. can you fix it? third, your first code dose not solve the problem. I tried it both in OpenModelica and Wolfram SystemModeller. and finally, you are absolutely right about removing sign() function. It was a stupid of me to add it :), though removing it does not solve my problem.

Comment: There also is `Modelica.Constants.pi` for `pi`.